# Default controller giving me a "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI" -"No type was found that matches the controller named 'tab'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to access an app on my localhost connected to IIS with the following endpoint I'm trying to hit **https://api.url.com/api/tab**. I have a `TabController.cs` in my Controllers folder. I also have a `Views/Tab/Index.cshtml` file and am wondering why I'm getting the following two errors:

```
<Error>
<Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://api.url.com/api/tab'.</Message>
<MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'tab'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I have the same folder structure for a controller named `Footer`, and I'm able to access **`https://api.url.com/api/footer`** successfully. I've included my `WebApiConfig.cs` and `RouteConfig.cs` code below:

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I've a feeling it's something quite obvious I'm missing as I'm a bit new to .NET and the MVC structure. So any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to access the MVC Controller (inherited from the `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`) as if it's the Web API Controller (inherited from  the `System.Web.Http.ApiController`). As you know API controllers have their own routing configuration, which is completely separate from the rest of
the application. Therefore, to access an action method from the regular MVC controller  don't use `api` prefix in the URL. Just enter `https://api.url.com/tab` to call the default action method in the `tab` controller.

Comment: Okay, I added the proper using statement just to use the ApiController interface, but I'm now getting a "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'" and beneath that a "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed." error. I have my dbcontext in another layer, so I'm not sure why this would be thrown.

Comment: Actually @Jackdaw, my previous comment is a whole separate question. Your answer was the response to my original question and got rid of that particular error message. Thank you!

Comment: @jmath412: It is necessary include the related code to the post to be able understand what causes the error. Post a new question with related code and we will try to help you. Regards.

Comment: Just created a new post for the newest error if you want to take a crack at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080920/calling-method-to-return-data-to-controller-and-getting-error-the-operation-c