# Calling method to return data to controller and getting error : "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm instantiating an instance of `DashboardActions.cs` inside of my `TabController.cs` which is suppposed to return an `IEnumerable<Tab>` coming from Entity Framework. I've shown the code for the GET method of the `TabController.cs` and the `GetTabs` method of the DashboardActions.cs class that the controller is instantiating.

**TabController.cs**

```
public IEnumerable<Tab> GetTabs()
        {
            IEnumerable<Tab> recentPages = null;

            try
            {
                using (var context = new Clarity.BusinessLayer.CLARITY_DNN())
                {
                    recentPages = (from t in context.Tabs
                                   join tp in context.TabPermissions on t.TabID equals tp.TabID
                                   where tp.RoleID == -1 && tp.AllowAccess && tp.PermissionID == 3
                                  && !t.IsDeleted && t.IsVisible && t.PortalID == 0 &&
                                  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Description)
                                   && t.TabName != "Home"
                                   select t)
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.LastModifiedOnDate ?? p.CreatedOnDate)
                    .Take(20);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            return recentPages;
       }
```

**TabController.cs**

```
public class TabController : ApiController
    {
       
        // GET: Dashboard
        public IEnumerable<Tab> Get()
        {
            var recentTabsInstance = new DashboardActions();
            var recentTabs = recentTabsInstance.GetTabs();

            return recentTabs;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See the following post about injecting the repository into the controller: [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just a query, not data. To get data from db you have to add .ToList()

```
recentPages = (from t in context.Tabs
               join tp in context.TabPermissions on t.TabID equals tp.TabID
               where tp.RoleID == -1 && tp.AllowAccess && tp.PermissionID == 3
               && !t.IsDeleted && t.IsVisible && t.PortalID == 0 &&
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Description)
                 && t.TabName != "Home"
               select t)
                 .OrderByDescending(p => p.LastModifiedOnDate ?? p.CreatedOnDate)
                .Take(20)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I added .ToList and got: "Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tab_3CD81772060539EC79CB677CA17899B90117059EFFC0976D087CA8B0FBE38520' with data contract name 'Tab_3CD81772060539EC79CB677CA17899B90117059EFFC0976D087CA8B0FBE38520:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer."

Comment: I haven't seen this before but am doing some research into it now.

Comment: @jmath412 I am sorry but it is a completely different error already. You have to create another post for it.  I only offered the solution for your question. There is a rule at this site - one question - one answer. To answer another question you need to post all classes that are participating in the query.

Comment: I was posting the results, thinking they may be related/of interest before starting my next post (if needed.) Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Pls, create another post if you need and I will try to help too along with another ones.